# delete extra blank lines in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

```
M-x flush-lines ^$
```

deletes all blank lines in a buffer. However I only want to delete extra blank lines, that is if there are n consecutive blank lines I want to delete n-1 and keep one.

I know that delete-blank-lines does the job for the blank lines under the point, however I want a simple solution which works for the whole buffer.

Any ideas how to do this? Especially is it possible to modify the regex ^$ from my first example to match only the extra lines?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
C-x h M-x replace-regexp RET ^ C-q C-j C-q C-j + RET C-q C-j RET
```

which marks the whole buffer and replaces two or more blank lines with a single blank line.

Comment: Similarly, you can do: `M-x replace-regexp RET ^ C-q C-j $ RET RET`. This will replace two consecutive blank lines with a single one.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about a built in function for this, but you can do:

M-x single-lines-only

```
(defun single-lines-only ()
  "replace multiple blank lines with a single one"
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n" nil t)
    (replace-match "\n")
    (forward-char 1)))
```

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>C-x C-o</kbd> (delete-blank-lines) does exactly that. You'll just need a little macro magic to run it on a whole buffer.

Comment: That's supposed to be `C-x C-o`, `C-x o` calls `other-window`.