# Emacs: highlight 2 or more empty lines

Tags: emacs, removing-whitespace, blank-line

I have entered the following code in my .emacs file to highlight unwanted white spaces.

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))
(global-whitespace-mode t)
```

This shows  (1) empty lines at the beginning & end of buffer
            (2) tabs
            (3) lines which go over the 80 character limit
            (4) trailing white spaces

I would like emacs to automatically highlight '2 or more empty lines'. Any ideas on how to implement this? I did find a [blog post](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/03/16/removing-blank-lines-buffer/) explaining a way to do this with the help of regexp, but I am not sure how to implement this in .emacs file.

Edit 1: Found a way to delete extra blank lines but this still doesn't help me with highlighting multiple blank lines automatically. [delete extra blank lines in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419576/delete-extra-blank-lines-in-emacs)

Edit 2: Adding the following to .emacs seems to work, but only after I save and reopen file in a buffer.

```
(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-regexp "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n" 'hi-yellow)))
```

Edit 3: After adding `(global-hi-lock-mode 1)` to .emacs file just before the line in Edit 2, it seems to highlight 1 or more empty lines within the buffer. I am not sure how to modify the regexp so that it will only accept 2 or more empty lines.

Comment: Have a look at `whitespace.el` -- `empty` is the `whitespace-style` that deals with lines at the end of the file and also at the beginning of the file -- see also the following, which will need to be tailored to your needs:  `(defcustom whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp "^\\([ \t\n]+\\)" "Specify regexp for empty lines at end of buffer.  Used when 'whitespace-style' includes 'empty'." :type '(regexp :tag "Empty Lines At End Of Buffer") :group 'whitespace)`.  One or more of the functions may need to be modified -- e.g., the function `whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp`.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks! I am not very well versed with lisp (started using emacs a week ago) but I will definitely have a look at file you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)).  That's what it's for.

Use command `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` (`C-x X h x`) or `hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end` (`C-x X h e`).   (To unhighlight a regexp, use `C-x X u x` or  `C-x X u e`.)

Interactively, you input the regexp to use as usual in Emacs (with `C-q C-j` to match a newline character, and no need for double backslashes), so you type `\(^\s-*$\) C-q C-j`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I was looking for a way to add this to .emacs file. Correct me if I am wrong but your suggested way will only work when I explicitly enter those commands every time I want those empty lines to be highlighted.

Comment: No, you need not use the functions in `highlight.el` interactively. You can use them just as well from your Lisp code. This is true of all Emacs commands, BTW (although yes, some commands are less useful in Lisp code). Anyway, no problem -- you can just use the functions in code. I do that all the time.

Comment: Perhaps I should also have pointed out that when a regexp is passed as a string argument to a Lisp function, it looks a bit different from what you type interactively for the same regexp.  In this example, you would pass the exact same string to the `highlight.el` functions as was shown in other answers to your question: "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n".  The interactive input `\(^\s-*$\) C-q C-j` produces exactly that string.

Answer (score 2):

Your `highlight-regexp`-solution can be made into a minor-mode with the following elisp (e.g., in your `.emacs` file).

You can activate the minor mode by right-clicking onto one of the mode-names in the mode-line and then selecting `nl2-mode`. You can deactivate the minor mode by clicking on `nl2` in the mode line and selecting `Turn off minor mode`.

To understand the code see the help for `define-minor-mode` and `define-key` (e.g., <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `define-minor-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>). Note, that in emacs also mouse clicks in menus count as key strokes.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode nl2-mode
  "Highlight two successive newlines."
  :global t
  :lighter " nl2"
  (if nl2-mode
      (highlight-regexp "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n" 'hi-yellow)
    (unhighlight-regexp "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n")))

(define-key mode-line-mode-menu [nl2-mode]
  `(menu-item ,(purecopy "nl2-mode") nl2-mode
  :help "Highlight two succesive newlines."
  :button (:toggle . (bound-and-true-p nl2-mode))))
```

There are several facts that make highlighting two consecutive empty lines more complicated (`font-lock` tends to only highlight non-empty regions, linebreaks are limits for the region to re-fontify, re-fontification after buffer changes are required).
The following code shows one way. Maybe, there are easier ways.

```lisp
(require 'font-lock)
(global-font-lock-mode)

(defface jit-lock-nl2-face '((default :background "yellow"))
  "Face to indicate two or more successive newlines."
  :group 'jit-lock)

(defun jit-nl2-extend (start end &optional old)
  "Extend region to be re-fontified"
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      ;; trailing:
      (goto-char end)
      (skip-chars-forward "[[:blank:]]\n")
      (setq jit-lock-end (point))
      ;; leading:
      (goto-char start)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (skip-chars-backward "[[:blank:]]\n")
      (unless (bolp) (forward-line))
      (setq jit-lock-start (point)))))

(defun jit-nl2 (jit-lock-start jit-lock-end)
  "Highlight two or more successive newlines."
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (jit-nl2-extend jit-lock-start jit-lock-end)
      ;; cleanup
      (remove-text-properties jit-lock-start jit-lock-end '(font-lock-face jit-lock-nl2-face))
      ;; highlight
      (while (< (point) jit-lock-end)
    (if (looking-at "[[:blank:]]*\n\\([[:blank:]]*\n\\)+")
        (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) 'font-lock-face 'jit-lock-nl2-face)
           (goto-char (match-end 0)))
      (forward-line))))))


(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda ()
                      (add-hook 'jit-lock-after-change-extend-region-functions 'jit-nl2-extend)
                      (jit-lock-register 'jit-nl2)
                      (jit-lock-mode 1)
                      ))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I entered the following code in my .emacs and it seems to work well. `(global-hi-lock-mode 1)`
`(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-regexp
                                               "\\(^\\s-*$\\)\n" 'hi-yellow)))`. The only problem is that it highlights single empty lines as well. I want it to highlight 2 or more empty lines if they are present within the code I am editing.

Comment: I think the problem therewith is that `jit-lock` (the working-horse of `font-lock`) already fontifies after one line break. So it sees always only one linebreak and extending the regular expression is not the right way. The portion of the buffer that is re-fontified after editing is just too small. But, there are other ways... I will try when I have some spare time.

Comment: Thanks! Will look forward to your solution.